# Vim autocomplete to include punctuation between words

Tags: vim, autocomplete

I am currently programming in tcl/tk. I have some widgets called `.entry,stdin` and `.entry,stdout` and I am using [supertab](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) for autocompletion. The comma is there because I am using a package called [gridplus](http://www.satisoft.com/tcltk/gridplus2) and that's how I can access the standard tk widget functionality.

The idea of using autocompletion is that when I type `.entry,` and press the tab key it will show ONLY `stdin` and `stdout` as possible answers. However when I do that it shows all the possible words in the file instead of just `stdin` and `stdout`. And when tried [autocomplpop](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoComplPop) and [neocomplcache](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.vim) it doesn't even pop the menu after `.entry,`

I guess vim is interpreting the `,` as a word separator even though there is no space. When I tried swapping `,` for `_` it works because I think vim is interpreting it as one word. So I guess is more to do with vim interpretation of what a word is, rather than a plugin matter. However, I am wondering if it is possible to change this behaviour.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add comma to the list of characters that are considered to be part of a keyword.  You'd almost certainly want to limit this to TCL files.  This could be done by placing the following in `~/.vim/ftplugin/tcl.vim`:

```
setlocal iskeyword+=,
```

I haven't tried this with supertab, but it does work with vim's builtin word completion.